# Partial specialization of the function template

Tags: c++, templates

I am a bit confused because I've read that partial specialization of the function template in C ++ is not possible, but it works for me (gcc 5.3.0).

My example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void fun(T1 a, T2 b){
    cout << "template\n";
}

template <typename T1>
void fun(T1 a, int b){
    cout << "Function partialy specialized\n";
}

int main(){

    fun("ab", "cd"); //template
    fun(2,2);        //Function partialy specialized
    fun("xx", 2);    // Function partialy specialized
}
```

How is it really correct?

Comment: This isn't a partial specialization.  It is an overload

Comment: Why is an overload?

Comment: Function overloading is the process of writing multiple functions that have the same name bu different parameters. i.e. `int foo(int);` and `int foo(double)`.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I can't understand why my example is function overloading, not partial specialization.

Comment: Could anyone provide me example with FUNCTION partial specialization according to my example?

Comment: Because there is no partial specialization for function templates.  So, instead of making a specialization you made an overload